# Flutter in_app_purchase plugin requires Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, in-app-purchase

Question: am I required to use Firebase if I need to implement in_app_purchase in my app?

The Google says to implement in app purchase, you have to use: pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

There is the codelab: codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#0

This lab shows Firebase in the pubspec file. Hence, I thought that the Firebase is required.

Can I use any database or I have to use Firebase to implement in app purchase?

Please let me know your thoughts when you get a chance.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty clear to me in the codelab itself that Firebase is not required.  It's just illustrated as a convenience so the codelab won't require you to implement an entire backend in order to get it to work.  From the [codelab text](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#5):

> While there are many ways to set up a backend service, you'll do this using cloud functions and Firestore, using Google's own Firebase.
>
> Writing the backend is considered out of scope for this codelab, so the starter code already includes a Firebase project that handles basic purchases to get you started.

Firebase is also never mentioned in the readme for the in_app_purchase package you linked.